# Does binary logging for MySQL slow down performance?

Tags: mysql

The question is simple. Does turning on binary logs in MySQL slow down performance considerably, i.e. will it write large amount of data to disk thereby causing high I/O, will it hog memory, does it have any implications for the CPU ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html)

Running a server with binary logging enabled makes performance slightly slower. However, the benefits of the binary log in enabling you to set up replication and for restore operations generally outweigh this minor performance decrement.

Comment: Does that mean that percona performance blog is incorrect saying the following "But enabling the binary log reduces MySQL’s performance dramatically. " here www.percona.com/blog/2010/10/23/mysql-limitations-part-2-the-binary-log/

Comment: define slightly , and define dramatically. Log will efect performance, that is for sure but I think no one can tell you how much. (I think it will be slightly, no metter what slightly means ;) )

Comment: I have 100 queries / second. If I'm correct about how bin_log works, it actually performs a write to disk for EACH of those. That's a humongous amount of writes. Sounds like it will come with an equally humongous cost in performance. I define humongous as somewhere between monster-super-duper-much and "damn, that's a lot".

Comment: Adergaard's comment links to https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/10/23/mysql-limitations-part-2-the-binary-log/ (there are non printable characters in his version)

Answer (score 3):

If the binary logs and the MySQL data write to the same disk mount, then yes it will slow things down.

If you create a separate disk mount just for logs, then it will not slow down as much.

In Facebook, [there is a Database Engineer who splits up the MySQL files into separate disks](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2009/05/tables-on-ssd-redobinlogsystem.html). In light of this example, you could just setup a second disk, map [**log-bin**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin) to that disk. That way, no wasted spindles writing log data on a data volume.

Comment: I agree with conception to have logs stored elsewhere (unless you have really bad ass storage with tremendous amount of IOPS and throughoutput...   Quote from MariaDB on this matter: [A MariaDB server with the binary log enabled will run slightly more slowly](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/overview-of-the-binary-log/)